# document.getElementById("").innerHTML output font color

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a code that loops through array of simple data values and print them out such that

```
<div id = "output"> Output Updates </div> 
<div id = "track"> Track </div> 
<div id = "results"> Results <br/></div>
```

.

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var data = [12, 22, 01, 8, 34];
var dataIndex = 0;
var counter = 0; // Trial 
var current = 0;
var previous = data[0];

var output = document.getElementById("output");

setInterval(function() {
    //output.innerHTML = data[dataIndex].x;
    current = data[dataIndex];
    output.innerHTML = current;
    if (current > previous){
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += + current + " <br/>";
    }
    else if (current == previous) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += + current + " <br/>";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += + current + " <br/>";
    }

    previous = current;
    dataIndex = (dataIndex + 1) % data.length;

}, 500)
```

what I want to do is that 
if (current>previous) condition, then print the result in a green font 
else if (current == previous) condition, then print the result in a black font
else condition, then print the result in a red font

when I put a font color style to each conditions, it changes font color of every results that have already been printed

here is a jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/kmhz6kx0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element's direct text nodes can have only one color, but its children can have different colors.

Add a `div` with the desired color each time you update `results`:

```
if (current > previous) {
  color= 'green';
}
else if (current == previous) {
  color= 'black';
}
else {
  color= 'red';
}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += 
  '<div style="color: '+color+'">' +current + " </div>";
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p66wc8a8/)